# MimeMessage Content-Transfer-Encoding issue

Tags: java, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

Greetings all...
I am hoping somebody can shed me some lights about the issue I am having.

Reading the Javadoc of MimeMessage's getInputStream(), it says *"Return a decoded input stream for this Message's content*"
However, this is not what I am experiencing. The output is not decoded. For instance, if I have a message a follows

```
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2010 11:29:13 +1100
From: xxxxxxxxx
To: xxxxxxxxxxxx
Message-ID: <4B8472D9.5050901@xxxxxxxxx>
Subject: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="------------000801030004000206000901"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Organization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: Thunderbird 2.0.0.23 (Windows/20090812)

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------000801030004000206000901
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=3DISO-8859-1; format=3Dflowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

!

--------------000801030004000206000901
Content-Type: text/plain;
 name=3D"bla.bla"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: inline;
filename=3D"bla.bla"

 my.username =3D holly
my.host =3D molly
--------------000801030004000206000901--
```

Then, assuming that I have an object called 'm' constructed with the above content, then calling m.getInputStream() and dump the output to the screen shows those '=3D' charsets.
What did I do wrong?

If I used QPDecoderStream to decode the output of m.getInputStream() then of course the result will be correct. However, it defeat the purpose, because the Javadoc says getInputStream() returns a decoded input stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the message is malformed.  [You're not allowed to set `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to `quoted-printable` on a multipart part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.4):

> If a Content-Transfer-Encoding header field appears as part of a
> message header, it applies to the entire body of that message.  If a
> Content-Transfer-Encoding header field appears as part of an entity's
> headers, it applies only to the body of that entity.  If an entity is
> of type "multipart" the Content-Transfer-Encoding is not permitted to
> have any value other than "7bit", "8bit" or "binary".

You could probably get the top-level `MimeMessage`'s decoded content stream and instantiate a `MimeMultipart` from it, but that's just hacking around the fundamental problem of a broken message.

Comment: Thank you very much. This explained why it has been behaving as it is.